# How does github display any file with valid file extension?

Tags: github, mime-types, file-extension

What allows GitHub to display the contents of any file with a valid file name and extension (e.g. `readme.md`), or no extension at all (e.g. `readme`) immediately after pushed?

Is the file's mimetype being checked?
Does GitHub maintain a list of all possible valid file extensions?
Something else entirely?

A friend asked and I did not have an answer.

Comment: It's fairly easy for the file content to be checked to see what type of file it is - if it's not assumed to be text, most recognisable file formats have known header formats in the first few bytes. I doubt GitHub even bothers with the filename, mimetype or extension - it just reads the file as it is uploaded and determines the file content from the first few bytes.

Comment: When you say 'display', are you talking about syntax highlighting, or something else?

Comment: @Jake I literally mean display the contents, as seen here https://github.com/brianzelip/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/.zshrc . The question is how does github know how to display a `.zshrc` file? @adelphus mentioned header information.